# BBB Site can't be reached, took too long time to respond. For some clients for particular network

Tags: amazon-web-services, webrtc, firewall, turn, bigbluebutton

I set up my BigBlueButton server on the cloud-hosted at Singapur where my client devices are located in India. Some client devices BBB is working fine and for particular ips client browser throws `Site can't be reached`. I am using my own TURN server and that is also located at Singapur hosted data centre. I tried to fix from BBB and TURN server configurations but I could not find any working solution. [Here is my question on BBB forum](https://groups.google.com/g/bigbluebutton-setup/c/_5mK4gc5xYI/m/qVcmCQqPBwAJ). I tried changing the configurations of TURN in `/etc/systemd/system/coturn.services` as suggested in the above discussion but that also could not help. Following are observations regarding this issue.

- When I tried o ping BBB server from client machine where this error is coming then `ping server_ip` throws the request timeout.
- When I switch to another network from same client device then BBB works fine & ping also works.
- In some cases it resolved on restarting the client wifi router. 
  I am unable to find the exact reason behind this issue, Is it the issue due to TURN or BBB setup? Or Is it the issue from my server infrastructure? What could be the possible solutions or any workarounds to resolve it?